# Problema em chamar método no AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android

Quero chamar um método no Android Studio, após o usuário selecionar uma opção. Porém, já tentei de diversas formas através do getItemId(), porém, eu chamo o método e nada ocorre. Será um problema no método takeScreenshot, ou eu deveria utilizar um new Intent? Se sim, como eu poderia fazer isso?

```
          @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.main_add_sticker) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, StickerSelectActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_STICKER_REQUEST_CODE);
        return true;
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.main_remove_sticker) {
        motionView.deletedSelectedEntity();
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.main_change_image) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Selecione uma imagem"), PICK_IMAGE);
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.main_save_croqui) {
        takeScreenshot();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void takeScreenshot(){
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

    try {
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/" + now + ".jpg";

        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        openScreenshot(imageFile);



    } catch (Throwable e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void openScreenshot (File imageFile){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/");
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: Aparece algum erro no log?

Comment: Não acontece nada, simplesmente...

Comment: Logue no console o resultado de `getItemId()`, ele está aparecendo corretamente?

Comment: Está sim, mas o método parece que não é chamado, simplesmente. Eu deveria colocar this. ou algo assim? Sou bem iniciante...

Comment: Está entrando no `if` certo? Logue alguma coisa em cada if e veja se ta tudo certo. Se estiver,verifique se a função `takeScreenshot` está sendo chamada, logue algo no console dentro dela?

Comment: É isso, todos os ifs funcionam, as demais funcionalidades são chamadas. Como eu faço pra testar se a função está sendo chamada, simulando pelo smartphone?

Comment: Sempre que estiver com algum problema a primeira coisa a fazer é colocar logs por toda a aplicação, assim você saberá por onde seu aplicativo está passando, os valores das variáveis e onde ele parou (último log). Assim que se testa se uma função ou qualquer outra coisa está funcionando como esperado

Comment: Tipo isso? https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/?hl=pt-br

Comment: Exatamente esse _"Grave mensagens de registro no seu código"_